# Custom font-variation-axis being set results in Chrome not displaying font

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, webkit

I have a variable ttf font that I've created with one axis, optical sizing or opsz, using [Glyphs 2.6.1](https://glyphsapp.com/). In Firefox 65, going to use this axis works as expected, text becomes thicker when the axis is bumped.

In Chrome 72 and Safari 12.0.3, using the axis results in the glyph not being displayed at all.

Comment: Does the interpolation work properly when using [FontView](https://github.com/googlei18n/fontview), and are you using the font locally or through `@font-face`?

Comment: @kennethormandy yes, it works in FontView. And I'm using `@font-face` to avoid font caching issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Build 1220, the patch notes of Glyphs included a note about about always including a `cvar` table.

With this addition, the font renders and respects my font variation axis in Webkit.